# Which of these has continuous sample path?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Which or these statements is true and what is the rule for continuous space:

$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$, where $Z = \{ Z_t: 0\leq t\leq 10 \}$:

1) $Z_t(\omega) := t*\omega$

- Z has continuous sample path

2) $Z_t(\omega) := I_{[t,\infty]}(\omega)$

- Z has continuous sample path
- Z has right continuous sample path

3) $Z_t(\omega) := I_{[-t,t]}(\omega)$

- Z has continuous sample path
- all the sample paths of Z are continuous (does this paraphrased sentence makes difference)

4) $Z_t(\omega) := t*I_{[-1,1]}(\omega)$

- Z has continuous sample path
- all the sample paths of Z are continuous (does this paraphrased sentence makes difference)

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know which of the statements are true, how to evaluate Indicative function. For example for 2) if t = 0 I would say its continuous, for t=5 I am not sure if I can say Z = 0 for all omega <5, but then is it continous?

Comment: You need to check that for each $\omega$, the dependence on $t$ is continuous.  In 2), for example, when $t$ passes through $\omega$ there is a jump discontinuity.

Comment: Yes, but that would still count as right/left continuity:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function. So there are 4 examples, 7 statements, which one are true/false

Comment: Yes, it's left continuous or right continuous.

Comment: So, all these examples have continuous path?